# import .cert file to azure keyvault issues

Tags: azure-devops, ssl-certificate, azure-keyvault

I uploaded a .cert certificate as secure file in azure devops

we are using Classic pipelines

my pipeline added two additional tasks

1, download secure file

2, Azure Cli task to import .cert file add below script as inline script

$certFilePath  = $(Agent.TempDirectory)\mycert.com.crt
az keyvault certificate import --vault-name "keyvaultname" -n "mycert.com.crt"  -f $certFilePath

getting the below error

D:\agent_work_temp\mycert.com.crt : The term 'D:\agent_work_temp\mycert.com.crt' is not recognized as the name
of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At D:\agent_work_temp\azureclitaskscript1675572660483_inlinescript.ps1:1 char:12

- $inFile  = D:\agent_work_temp\mycert.com.crt
- ```
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  ```

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (D:\agent_work_temp\mycert.com.crt:String) [], ParentContainsErrorRe
    cordException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce the same in my lab environment and got the below results.

Firstly, I would like to inform you that the file type of the certificate to be imported must be the **.pfx** or **.pem** extension. Kindly refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/certificates/tutorial-import-certificate?tabs=azure-portal) for more details.

[image]

I have followed the below steps to upload a **.pfx** file to the Azure Key Vault.

Step 1: Created a **.pfx** type certificate.

Step 2: Upload a file to the secure files in Azure DevOps.

[image]

Step 3: Add below mentioned tasks to the pipeline.

[image]

[image]

Command: `az keyvault certificate import --vault-name "key-vault-vijay" --file "$(Agent.TempDirectory)\test05.pfx" --name "cert0104" --password "passw0rd@123"`

Pass the password parameter if you have created it at the time of certificate file creation.

Step 4: Verify the access policies assigned to the service principle using Azure DevOps automation on the key vault.
[image]

Step 5: Run the pipeline and kindly check for the certificate on the Azure portal.
[image]

[image]

Kindly refer to this link Manage Azure Key Vault using CLI - Azure Key Vault | Microsoft Learn for more details.